# Error al hacer mas de una petición a un servidor socket en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Estoy tratando de crear un servidor socket en Python y un cliente que haga peticiones a este.

El problema esta principalmente en que, al hacer la primera petición del cliente al servidor, todo se hace correctamente, pero al volver a realizar una segunda petición, dar el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del archivo servidor.py es el siguiente:

```
import socket
import threading


def conexiones(socket_cliente):
    peticion = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    if seguir:
        print ("[*] Mensaje recibido: {}".format(peticion))
        message = "Mensaje recibido"
        byt = message.encode()
        socket_cliente.send(byt);     

ip = "0.0.0.0" 
puerto = 5555 
max_conexiones = 5 
servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
seguir = True


servidor.bind((ip, puerto))
servidor.listen(max_conexiones)


print ("[*] Esperando conexiones en {}:{}".format(ip, puerto))

while True:
    cliente, direccion = servidor.accept()
    print ("[*] Conexion establecida con {}:{}".format(direccion[0] , direccion[1]))
    conexiones = threading.Thread(target=conexiones, args=(cliente,))
    conexiones.start()
```

Y el código del cliente que hace la petición el siguiente:

```
    import socket

servidor = "127.0.0.1"
puerto = 5555

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((servidor, puerto))
message = "HOLA SERVIDOR"
byt = message.encode()
cliente.send(byt);
respuesta = cliente.recv(4096)
print (respuesta)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es tienes una función `conexiones` y una variable `conexiones`. Cuando ejecutas la primera vez

`conexiones = threading.Thread(target=conexiones, args=(cliente,))`

Lo que asignas a `target` es la función, pero la variable `conexiones` la sobreescribes con el objeto tipo `Thread` que se crea.

Cuando lo llamas la segunda vez, asignas a `target` un objeto `Thread`, lo cual obviamente no es una función.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente se trataba de eso :)